# Hidden Markov Model in C++

Tags: c++, hidden-markov-models

I have been working on activity recognition problem using Opencv in linux environment. I reached up to sequence of symbol(using k-means clustering). And now I want to train those sequence of different activity using Hidden Markov Model in C++. But I don't know where to start? I went through this [code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cvhmm/) but didn't find the how to give different sequence and get the trained model?

Any help on this will be truly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You should browse the SO. One possible answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733090/issue-in-training-hidden-markov-model-and-usage-for-classification

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question is answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49997/hidden-markov-model-library).

There you can find some implementation in C++.